# DLL load failed while importing _cyrfc: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, saprfc

I'm trying to import pyrfc module and getting this error:

> DLL load failed while importing _cyrfc: The specified module could not be found.

Can someone help? This is for connecting to SAP source system.

Comment: Some DLL that `_cyrf` directly or indirectly depends on is missing or at the wrong location. With a tool like https://lucasg.github.io/Dependencies/ you may be able to find out which DLL it is.

Comment: 1. What Python version ? 2. How did you install pyrfc

Comment: @rasjani  3.11.3

Answer (score 0):

This problem was usually caused by incorrect python interpreter.

You can use shortcuts **Ctrl+Shift+P** and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to choose your python interpreter which you installed the package in.